# Creating hash value according to the HMAC-SHA512 method using PCL/MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I'm trying to create a cross platform application using MVVMCross and portable class libraries, which interacts with an api and displays some data asynchronously.
Currently I am trying to generate a SHA512 hash value for a sign key that will be sent along to the api.

I am not exactly sure how I can implement the cryptology portion. I have tried using the SHA512 class, however it appears to be unavailable. I tried manually adding a reference to System.Security.Cryptology which didn't help.

I also tried additional packages on nuget such as SharpCrypt to see if they would help generate a hash value, however I see the error "the type or namespace name 'CryptSharp' could not be found" after adding the package from nuget.

I am targeting:
.Net Framework 4.5+
Windows Store apps
Silver light 5
Windows Phone 8

I'm quite a beginner so maybe I am missing something extremely obvious, any help or examples would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe some of the crypto classes may also be available portably using the PCLContrib project - http://pclcontrib.codeplex.com - but I don't think this is yet available beyond Windows.

Where functionality isn't available portably, you can inject implementations into portable class libraries via an interface from each UI platform:

- there's an example of this in the first part of N=31 in http://mvvmcross.blogspot.co.uk
- there's a full introduction to MvvmCross dependency injection in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control